# MVC on mono looks for aspx files not routes

Tags: c#, apache, deployment, mono, centos

I'm trying to host MVC3 app on CentOS. I've setup Mono and apache, it works, but when I try access my site I get errors in apache log:

```
[Wed Feb 05 15:12:16 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_mono/2.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
mod-mono-server4
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_global
Root directory: /
[Wed Feb 05 15:12:21 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /Default.aspx denied
[Wed Feb 05 15:12:21 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.aspx denied
[Wed Feb 05 15:12:21 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /Default.aspx denied
[Wed Feb 05 15:12:21 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /default.aspx denied
[Wed Feb 05 15:12:21 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied
[Wed Feb 05 15:12:21 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html.var denied
```

This tells me that apache looking for classic aspx pages and not routes. How to set it up so it searches for routes?

**Edit**: mod_mono.conf:

```
<IfModule !mod_mono.c>
    LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Powered-By "Mono"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mono_module>
    #AddType application/x-asp-net .config .cs .csproj .dll .resources .resx .sln .vb .vbproj
    #AddType application/x-asp-net .asax .ascx .ashx .asmx .aspx .axd .browser .licx .master .rem .sitemap .skin .soap .webinfo

    MonoAutoApplication enabled
    MonoDebug true
    MonoServerPath "/opt/mono/bin/mod-mono-server4"
    MonoUnixSocket "/tmp/.mod_mono"

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex Default.aspx
    </IfModule>

    <DirectoryMatch "/(bin|App_Code|App_Data|App_GlobalResources|App_LocalResources)/">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </DirectoryMatch>

    <Location "/Mono">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
        SetHandler mono-ctrl
    </Location>
</IfModule>

AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asmx
AddType application/x-asp-net .ashx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asax
AddType application/x-asp-net .ascx
AddType application/x-asp-net .soap
AddType application/x-asp-net .rem
AddType application/x-asp-net .axd
AddType application/x-asp-net .cs
AddType application/x-asp-net .vb
AddType application/x-asp-net .master
AddType application/x-asp-net .sitemap
AddType application/x-asp-net .resources
AddType application/x-asp-net .skin
AddType application/x-asp-net .browser
AddType application/x-asp-net .webinfo
AddType application/x-asp-net .resx
AddType application/x-asp-net .licx
AddType application/x-asp-net .csproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .vbproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .config
AddType application/x-asp-net .Config
AddType application/x-asp-net .dll
DirectoryIndex index.aspx
DirectoryIndex Default.aspx
DirectoryIndex default.aspx
```

In httpd.conf I only have ServerName nad DocumentRoot for my vhost.

**EDIT #2** Following the advice here http://wordpressapi.com/solved-issue-directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive/ error disappeared, and now when I go to my site I see the files for browse.

Log now shows:

```
[Wed Feb 05 17:02:54 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_mono/2.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
mod-mono-server4
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_global
Root directory: /
[Wed Feb 05 17:03:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /srv/www/mvc3/bin/
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'mod-mono-server4, Version=2.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'mod-mono-server4, Version=2.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00308] in /tmp/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Hosting/ApplicationHost.cs:269 
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00037] in /tmp/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer/VPathToHost.cs:150 
  at Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer.GetApplicationForPath (System.String vhost, Int32 port, System.String path, Boolean defaultToRoot) [0x0009e] in /tmp/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer/ApplicationServer.cs:583 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer:GetApplicationForPath (string,int,string,bool)
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.GetOrCreateApplication (System.String vhost, Int32 port, System.String filepath, System.String virt) [0x000f9] in /tmp/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorker.cs:158 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.InnerRun (System.Object state) [0x000c9] in /tmp/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorker.cs:214 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.Run (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /tmp/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorker.cs:92 
[Wed Feb 05 17:03:18 2014] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Wed Feb 05 17:03:18 2014] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
[Wed Feb 05 17:03:19 2014] [notice] child pid 5068 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although i do not know about centos have't tried it,but it has been reported as bug on ubuntu 14.04 LTS here

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xsp/+bug/1293481

The problem is mod-mono-server4.exe crashes, mod-mono-server4.exe is the backend of mod_mono, mod_mono delegates all requests for asp.net from apache to mod-mono-server4.exe

I also faced this problem i am using mono 3.2.8 and i have found a partial workaround may be that can help you, add this to your mod_mono.conf just after MonoUnixSocket if you are using mono version i am using, you can try it on other versions too

```
MonoPath default /path/to/mono/4.5:/path/to
```

It should work after this change but after every restart of your computer it will give you some exceptions so you will need to restart your apache server and it will start working again,

one other thing if the above change worked and your mod-mono-server4.exe do not crash and you still get files for browse than try adding this to your mod_mono.conf

```
<IFModule mono_module>
    ForceType application/x-asp-net
........
```